# Regex conditional replacement in java but in the replacing string not in the regex itself

Tags: java, regex

I have a situation where the source String can be everything and is beyond the users control.
The user can provide the regex and the replacement value to replace the source string with whatever he wants to get the desired resulting string.
The problem is that the user should be able to provide a regex group with there specific replacements
For example:
if the sourcestring = "1" then the user can make a regex that replaces it with "on" but at the same time that when sourcestring = "2" it gets replaced with "off" and anything else gets replaced with "N/A".
In code i probably would do something like 
sourcestring.replace("([1])|([2])", ($1.equals("1")) ? "on" : ($2.equals("2") ? "off" : "N/A"));
but the second operand of the replace should be a string that the user chose and could also contain these conditions.
Is there a way to do this kind of operation ?

Comment: So... why not have multiple expression/replacement pairs?  Then you could just run each replacement, and if it matches, it's replaced.  If it doesn't match, maybe the next one will match.  I may be misunderstanding the question, though.

Comment: because the input is from a web form and i would only like 1 field for the regex and one for the replacement value. Of course i have considered making an array from the replacement string (for example ; separated) and changing $1 with the first value from the array etc but that did not seamed ideal

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a custom notation.

Have the user provide capturing groups and the replacement values per group.  E.g.,

"Hello, World, how are you?"

```
(Hello\W+World\W+)\s*(how\sare)\s*(you.*)

1 = Yo, man,
2 = sup
3 = yo?
```

Then write supporting java code.